# facing No xulrunner found running on port=5000 error when trying to access console from ssu app

Tags: ruby, xulrunner

I'm trying to run `ssu APP` https://github.com/wesabe/ssu on `ubuntu 10.04`. `bin/server` command executed without any issues but when I am trying to access console [script/console], I am facing below error :

> No xulrunner found running on port=5000!

I have verified all the services that are running in the system, In that list I could not find xulrunner service running on 5000 port.

Can anyone please let me know what might be the possible solution to fix this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, below mentioned fix as resolved the issue :

In application/chrome/content/wesabe/download/Controller.coffee

changed Server = require 'io/http/Server'

to

Server = require 'io/http/server'